# Parameter declaration missing exception creating Clojure Namespace

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting to create a new namespace in a new file for a Clojure project and when I try to compile I get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration missing, compiling:(algtone/algorithms/hilbert.clj:5:30)"

In file src/algtone/algorithms/hilbert.clj

```
(ns
   ^{:doc "Hilbert curve implementation"
     :author "Me"
    }
algtone.algorithms.hilbert)
```

Comment: This compiles for me. I don't think the problem is related to the ns declaration.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: I created a new Lein project and went into the base project folder and then into src/algtone/algorithms and made a file called hilbert.clj with the namespace declaration provided above. When I go back into the base folder (parent of src) and run lein repl I'm greeted with the provided error. As mac said above, I'm guessing I'm just messing up the compilation step or not putting things in the right spot. I'm just trying to separate out my project source files into different folders, though I'm very new with clojure and lein. Thanks for your continued help.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happen if you execute the code in a REPL? here everything works fine:

```
user=> (ns
  #_=>    ^{:doc "Hilbert curve implementation"
  #_=>      :author "Me"
  #_=>     }
  #_=> algtone.algorithms.hilbert)
nil
algtone.algorithms.hilbert=>
```